# Should one say "on even weeks" or "in even weeks"

Tags: prepositions, determiners, time

Could you tell me about the right preposition in this phrase: on/in even weeks in contrast with on/in odd weeks? Besides, is the determiner THE necessary before the noun WEEK and why is it or is it not?

Comment: *Odd* and *even* are generally used to describe numbers and numbered rows or seats. Weeks might better be described as *alternate*, if you are referring to every second week in a series.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition you want to use is

> on
>
> on even weeks

means on the second, forth, sixth, eighth, etc week of the year.

In your usage "on" = "during", since during those weeks you do *something*, or "at that appointed time".

> There is bus service **on** even weeks.
>   *there is bus service every other week.*
>
> The clock chimes **on** the hour.
>   *the clock chimes at the hour*.